# error in \ref-numbering for figures in tufte-latex

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, tufte

please run this mini-example:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:f1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{marginfigure}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 2}
    \label{fig:f2}
\end{marginfigure}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 3}
    \label{fig:f3}
\end{figure}

Fig. \ref{fig:f1}
Fig. \ref{fig:f2}
Fig. \ref{fig:f3}

\end{document}
```

it just creates a number for the second figure! the other ones stay empty! can anybody help me? (mactex 2012, tufte-latex 3.5.0, pdfLatex)

---

thank you!

now i found out, that the package "subfigure" was activated in a tufte-book-local.tex wich i forgot to delete from the same directory for the the mini example. it somehow destroys the figure counter.

sorry! but without your help i would have searched much longer :)

---

this post can be deleted!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The captions are all there, they are simply over-printing each other. if you add a bit of text they space out.

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:f1}
\end{figure*}
aaa\\
aaa\\
aaa\\
aaa\\
aaa

\begin{marginfigure}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 2}
    \label{fig:f2}
\end{marginfigure}

bbb\\
bbb\\
bbb

\begin{figure}
\rule{1in}{1in}
    \caption{Figure 3}
    \label{fig:f3}
\end{figure}

ccc

Fig. \ref{fig:f1}
Fig. \ref{fig:f2}
Fig. \ref{fig:f3}

\end{document}
```